# Why does the JTextfield and JButton only appear after starting the programm 3 times?

Tags: java

When i start the Programm it does not show the JTextfield and the JButton it only shows a blank Frame. The moment i restart it shows the JTextfield and if i restart it again it shows the JButton, why doesnt it show both directly?

(i just started with coding and do not realy have a clue, hope you do not get cancer reading my code :D)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class Interface {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame Fenster = new JFrame();   // Aufruf eines Fensters

        Fenster.setSize(360,600);  // Breite,Höhe des Fensters
        Fenster.setVisible(true);  //Sichtbarkeit des Fensters = true
        Fenster.setTitle("asdf"); // Name des Fensters festlegen 
        Fenster.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Fürs Schliessen
        Fenster.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true); //Look and Feel?????
        Fenster.setResizable(false); // Ob man die Grö0e verändern kann 

        JTextField Eingabe = new JTextField(); //Aufruf des Textfeldes





        Eingabe.setBounds(7,30,340,30);
        Eingabe.setLayout(null);

        Fenster.add(Eingabe);

        JButton Enter = new JButton(); 

        Enter.setBounds(280, 80, 50, 50);
        Fenster.add(Enter);
```

Comment: Swing methods must be called in the AWT event dispatch thread, not the main thread.  You can do this by moving all of your code into a Runnable, and passing that Runnable to [EventQueue.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place `Fenster.setVisible(true);` at the end of main() function